# "to prefer something over something" or "to prefer something to something"

Tags: word-choice, grammar, differences, prepositions, word-usage

Which syntax is more correct:

> to prefer something over something else

or

> to prefer something to something else

or maybe both are correct?

Comment: I don't have any facts, thus I am putting this in a comment.  I generally like to use the "something to something" version, I would still understand "something over something" though.

Comment: The syntax is identical, it's the wording that is different.

Comment: Whichever you prefer over the other.

Comment: Oh no, I more prefer one than the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that both are correct.  In fact, I use and hear both formulations used interchangeably.

---

However, I do think that using *over* creates more emphasis than using *to*.  This may be a personal preference, and I don't think that misuse of this would screw up your message.  But, like I said, I notice that I use the prepositions in this way:

For example, if I was trying to clearly distinguish Mary's cooking from John's cooking, I might say:

> I prefer Mary's cooking over John's cooking.  He just doesn't have what it takes to be good cook.

But, if I wanted to show a preference while not making it so strong, I would use *to*:

> I prefer Mary's cooking to John's, but he's still very talented.

Answer (score 5):

Both sentences are *gramatically correct.*

> The Survey found that a majority of customers preferred  Brand *A* **to**
>   Brand *B*.

- it implies that you want *A*, but don't want *B*

> The Survey found that a majority of customers preferred  Brand A
>   **over** Brand B.

- it implies that you want A, however you can settle for B, too.

However, "[prefer to"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/prefe) is **the phrase**, makes grammatical as well as semantic sense.

> ```
>     I prefer tea to coffee.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If an action is involved I'd use *over*. If it's an object I'd use *to*. For example:

- I prefer biking over walking.
- I prefer a cup of coffee to a cup of tea.

Comment: [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prefer+tea+to%2Cprefer+tea+over%2Cprefer+sitting+to%2Cprefer+sitting+over&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprefer%20tea%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprefer%20sitting%20to%3B%2Cc0) seem to indicate that _to_ is used far more frequently with both nouns and the more verby forms you mention (often called gerunds).